# cannot read property 'then' when calling axios in helper function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I separated out an axios call into another file called ApiMethods.js.

Now, whenever I try to use the 'uploadSpecFile' function inside ApiMethods.js, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Here is that helper method:

```
export function uploadSpecFile(formData, engineId) {
    return
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `/api/engineData/spec-files/${engineId}/files/upload`,
        data: formData,
        config: {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        }
    })
}
```

And I use it here:

```
import {  uploadSpecFile } from '/ApiMethods';

// error occurs here  **
uploadSpecFile(bodyFormData, this.props.engineId).then(response => {

        this.setState({
            selectedFile: response.data,
            file: null
        });
    })
    .catch(response => {
    });
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `undefined`, since `axios` is not on the same line as the return statement.

Just move the `axios` request to the same line and it will work as expected.

```
export function uploadSpecFile(formData, engineId) {
  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `/api/engineData/spec-files/${engineId}/files/upload`,
    data: formData,
    config: {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
    }
  });
}
```